# How to resolve AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response in Django Rest Framwork

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

While I am calling Django url, I get an error:

**AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response.**

My code is:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer
from myapp.models import employees
from .serializers import EmployeeSerializer

@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))

def getData(request):
    employees = {'name':'Bill', 'location':'Kolkata' }
    return Response(employees)

def getEmployees(request):
    employee_list = employees.objects.all()
    serializer = EmployeeSerializer(employee_list, many = True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should not be any line spaces between `@api_view` decorators and the views `getData`  and  `getEmployee` should have its individual decorators too

```
@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))
def getData(request):
    employees = {'name':'Bill', 'location':'Kolkata' }
    return Response(employees)

@api_view(('GET',))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))
def getEmployees(request):
    employee_list = employees.objects.all()
    serializer = EmployeeSerializer(employee_list, many = True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```